# Javascript format special time

Tags: javascript, time

I have from a software a output like this timevalue:

```
15606260000 s
```

I don't know what format this is. The value in minutes is approximately 30 minute

How can I convert this with javascript in hour:min:seconds?
I think this is a epoch time or so?

Comment: Does the software's documentation not tell you what it is?

Comment: I'm afraid not. I'm still looking with the manufacturer, but I'm looking for a while to find out the format. I only know that this number is about 30 minutes.

Comment: Looks like the number of sceconds of about 26 minutes multiplied by 10 millions. If you divide it by 10.000.000 and then by 60 you get 26,010 minutes.

Comment: @Lelio Faieta: Great. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

this looks like a unix timestamp value (count in seconds since 01/01/1970) 
what you can do in javascript is:

```
let d = new Date(15606260000); console.log(d.getUTCHours() + ":"+ d.getUTCMinutes() +":"+ d.getUTCSeconds());
```

and you can take it from there
You can use this link for a proper documentation
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date

keep in mind that JS time is in milliseconds most of the times you need to multiply by 1000